# DBContext cache expression tree of a query

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, expression-trees, dbcontext

I'm actually working on a project who use a very big linq to entity query (around 250 lines) who works with a lot of different entities.

This query depend of few parameters (3 or 4 max) so I think to "store" the expression tree of my query and modifying this one with just my few parameters like this.

```
IQueryable<Foo> myQuery = 
  GetBaseQuery()
  .Where(a => a.Param1 == "foo")
  .Where(a => a.Param2 == "bar");
```

Apart using compiled queries, is there a way to do that ?

This problem has some conditions

- I use DbContext and changing to ObjectContext is difficialy possible and it seems that this is a pre requities for using compiled queries.
- I use Visual Studio 2010 so... i'm limited to .NET 4 and entity framework 4.3 (no .NET 4.5, EF5 and autocompiled queries unhopefully)

So, Is there a way to

- Store an expression tree who will be just used as a "base" and will not take too much time to be generated ?
- Or using .NET 4.5 in visual studio 2010 ?
- Or using Compiled queries with a DbContext

REALLY Thank's by advance !!!

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Why can't you create the whole expression tree every time? I really doubt it will take significant time when compared with the time it takes to execute the SQL query´and the network roundtrips.

Comment: About 5 seconds to get all the stuff, 0.5 to retrieve data via SQL. It seemws that as complicated as the linq query is, as the expression tree rendering long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading between the lines, it seems you want compiled queries with DbContext. (This isn't really the same as storing the LINQ expression tree, but that doesn't seem to be the performance bottleneck in the testing we have done anyway.) As far as I know the options you have are:

- Use EF5 with .NET 4.5. Even if you are using VS2010 and targeting .NET 4 if you install .NET 4.5 on the machine where the app is run then you will get auto-compiled queries.
- Use EF6 with .NET 4 or .NET 4.5. EF6 moves the auto-compiled query code out of the .NET Framework so it gets used even when running on .NET 4.
- Use ObjectContext and CompiledQuery

I'm not aware of any way to use CompiledQuery with DbContext and there also aren't any plans to make this work.

Comment: Use EF5 with .NET 4.5 : You said that it's possible to use .NET 4.5 with VS 2010 ? Have you tried that ? It seems to me to be the best solution.

Comment: Yes, but it won't look like you are using .NET 4.5. Your application will still be targeting .NET 4, you'll only be able to use the .NET 4 APIs, and so on. But .NET 4.5 is an in-place update which means that when installed it replaces .NET 4. This means that any code running on the box will now be using .NET 4.5 even though it was only built to use .NET 4. And this means that it will use auto-compiled queries.

Comment: Ok. Have you find some valuable documentation on how to do that ? Out of the box when I install .NET 4.5 SDK, i can only get EF 4.3 (because nuget see that i use .NET 4 so no EF5)

Comment: NuGet will install EF5 on VS2010 with a simple "install-package EntityFramework". I just did it a few seconds ago.

Comment: I did the same but DefaultQueryPlanCachingSetting property to check auto compiled queries is not available. So i checked the entity framework dll version and see 4.3 instead of 5 (on a fresh mvc 3 project)

Comment: Yes, that property will not be available. But it is on by default. You will need to install/upgrade from NuGet to get EF5. The assembly version will be 4.4.